# Automatically Insert file-modification-time after @date command

Tags: python, doxygen

I'm documenting python code with doxygen
and I would like to use the @date command
to show the file-modifiation-date/time.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an input filter that adds the file modification date to the @date command. The following perl file would do the trick:

```
use File::stat;
$fn = $ARGV[0];
$time = localtime stat($fn)->mtime;
open F,"<$fn";
while (<F>)
{
  s/\@date/\@date $time/;
  print $_;
}
close F;
```

If you save this as `filemod.pl` you can make doxygen use the filter for each input file by setting the following in the configuration file:

```
INPUT_FILTER = "perl filemod.pl"
```